# Scroll View and Content view not automatically resizing in different views

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, ios9

I am trying to design a scroll view app in XCode 7 .I am just getting my head cracked over the fact that my scroll view and content view are not adjusting as per screen size. I changed my view controller size to freeform and set size to 600 * 700,size class being (wAny hAny) . I did so because I needed this much space for my designing purposes and not more than that.

I wanted that whenever any screen that measures beyond a height of 700 like 5.5" screen then the screen would not scroll and it should not scroll and display the contents normally as per my design but it would scroll for any size below 700. For this purpose I had designed my screen as per the following steps:-

Problem - My scroll view is working fine for screen sizes below height 700 but when it moves above the particular screen size it shows a blank space at the bottom of the content view i.e content view always takes the height of 700 and it is not adjusting as per the screen size . So what is the reason of this and what can be the solution?

1)Scroll view -

[image]

2)Content View -

[image]

3) Label placed in the content view

[image]

This is what my main story board looks like -

[image]

Here is how my screen runs in an iPad having height much greater than my freeform height i.e 700.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that contentViews size is adjusted automatically by its content. And its content is your label, which has a 339 top constraint and a 340 bottom constraint. So the content size will be about 680 in height. This is why your contentView isn't getting bigger.

Looks like a more generic problem, because you dont have to scroll for only one label. If you keep working like this (always place items inside your contentView with a specific space to top and bottom) you will have no problems with the size of your content view because it will resize automatically.

Comment: See anything I place in the content view it keeps the space but if I change the spacing as per an iPad size class i.e wRegular hRegular it fills up the space. So will it fill the space for all iPad sizes. If it is not then my constraints for content view isn't right. Please give some suggestions and have a look over my constraints.

Comment: You have said to keep specific space on top and bottom . What do you exactly mean by "specific" ? Here too I have given top space of 339 & bottom of 340.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the label on the middle it is simple. just delete the layout between your label and the left margin.